# Refreshing UItableView Data from a frequently changing NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

i've a `UITableView` and I'm reading a data from a web service.
the data from the web service may change at any time, so i have to refresh my data periodically.

i've managed to refresh the data and store it in an `NSArray`, but the `UITableView` won't display those data.

i tried

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

but it have no effect.

**EDIT:**

i've implemented all the methods to load the data from an `NSArray` to the `UiTableView`.
this works when the `NSArray` is initialized in the ViewDidLoad.

but if the `NSArray` changed while the application is running, the `UITableView` Will not display those changes.

Comment: if the table view displays at least the first set of data, you probably have a mistake in data source method when updating cell value. could you post the code for `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` ?

Comment: the UITableView does not show anything since my NSArray is of length 0 when the view is loaded. but it is populated after the view is loaded and i have to do that because my data is updated frequently.  imagine it as a Forex tableview.

Comment: so the IBOutlet is wired up? the method that updates the datasource with new information is def getting called and the array def has values in it after the update method has completed? I'd double check all this by stepping through it, it usually is something simple you overlooked.

Comment: In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, can you put an NSLog to print out the array to see if the array has the updated data and also to see if it get called when the myTableView reloadData is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate protocol, specifically `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Use this method to set up the cell. You can use the `row` property of `indexPath` to determine which cell you are setting up and provide it with data from your array.

For example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
id item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // Whatever data you're storing in your array
cell.textLabel.text = [item description]; // Substitute this for whatever you want to do with your cell.
}
```

**EDIT:**
`reloadData` should call 
`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` and 
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
 
to see if there are any cells to be drawn. Make sure you implement these methods as well and return non-zero values or your table view won't try to draw any cells and `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` won't be called.

**Parse**
You may also be interested in [this library](http://blog.parse.com/2011/12/28/parse-powered-ios-table-views/) which claims to make remote data-driven tables a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function where you put the content into the table.